# How to access a method of parent window of an Iframe [Chrome browser ]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I tried many times and many ways to call the method from inside the `iframe` while not yet successful to do so. please see below,

1. `main.html :` consisting the two iframe
2. iframe-1 linked with a index.html from where i want to call a method of main.html or want to change the src of second iframe.

**main.html**

```
<html> 
    <head> </head>
    <body>
     <iframe id="iframe-1" src="index.html"></iframe>
     <iframe id="iframe-2" ></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

**index.html**

```
<html> <head> 
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
    // How to access the method of main.html and change the iframe src
 });
</script>
</head> <body>
    ......
</body> </html>
```

Note : tried `parent.methodName()`, `window.parent.methodName()` not working

@EDIT : success on IE & MOZILLA but getting error on Chrome ( Cannot call method 'getElementById' of undefined )

Comment: @Ron's solution is working on mozilla and IE while i am getting error on Chrome

Answer (score 1):

You should try with

```
document.getElementById("iframe-1").contentWindow.func();
```

or

```
var $f = $("#myIFrame");
var fd = $f[0].document || $f[0].contentWindow.document; // document of iframe
fd.MyFunction();  // run function
```

[Docs](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/calling-function-inside-an-iframe)

Comment: Thanks @Baadshah but my question is either to access the main window method or change the `src` of sibling iframe.

Answer (score 1):

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function run() {
            window.parent.document.getElementById("iframe-2").src = "/test.html";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="run();">
</body>
</html>
```

How about this?

Or create a method inside main.html and access it using:
  window.parent.**methodname**();

Ron.

ps. window.parent.**methodname**(); works perfectly for me when I have a method in main.html

**main.html**

```
<html> 
    <head> </head>
    <script>
        function foo() {
            alert(1);
        }       
    </script>
    <body>
       <iframe id="iframe-1" src="index.html"></iframe>
       <iframe id="iframe-2" ></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I want to access from `index.html` instead of 'main.html' as you described the method which access the iframe from main.html and it's not the solution of my question.

Comment: I clarified my post a bit, because I think this is doing exactly what you want. Accessing a method or IFRAME (declared in main.html) from inside index.html.

Comment: Thanks Ron. Yes it works on Mozilla and IE while chrome is giving error. I was keep checking only on chrome, I should have checked it earlier on IE & mozilla too. Any idea for Chrome ?

Comment: Where do you use getElementById exactly? More specific, on which object? If I test my 2 HTML pages in Chrome it is working normally. window.parent.document.getElementById should work.

Comment: Can you post the piece of code where the error occurs? Or better yet both HTML pages including the Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

I am keeping this short.

As you are looking forward for the iframes/frames on same document[window sharing]. To access a variable defined in one document inside another document.You have to use document.importNode(original Node as in other document,boolean) method as per DOM 2.
Do something like this for javacript code ...

```
iframe=document.getElementsTagName("iframe")[0];
```

documentI(original variable/node present here)-

```
OriginalNode=iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName(//Tag name of Node//)
```

documentII(node to be cloned here)-                                                                                                        `iframe.contentWindow.document.importNode(OriginalNode,True)`

Node can be created of any method,property or object in any iframe by simple DOM methods.
This would work