# How to make jQuery available inside each iframe as default?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm working on a code playground type of web app. On each page there are upto 6 iframes containing results of whatever HTML/JS/CSS code a user creates/plays with.

I want to make jQuery available inside the head of each iframe as *default*.

Note that jQuery is available in the  of the parent window so I was thinking if there could be a way to avoid six independent requests being fired from each of the iframe [heads] for the same script?

Comment: Could you simply access the jquery script embedded in the parent? Like described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17612514/how-to-access-a-method-of-parent-window-of-an-iframe-chrome-browser - this is more general but you'll get the idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

When you create the iframe's content, you add the following code (or altered to use the "$"):

```
<!-- This goes in the "head" tag -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    //We're creating jQuery
    var jQuery = window.parent.jQueryLoader.getJQuery();
</script>
```

In your parent, you'd have this:

```
var jQueryLoader {
    getJQuery: function() { return JQuery );
};
```

Comment: Are you sure this will get you the right global state for jQuery, default document, `.data()` storage and all that? Also, your code as written doesn't make sense. You're trying to call `jQueryLoader.getjQuery()`, but `jQueryLoader` doesn't have a `getjQuery` property.

Comment: Also why do this rather than just make a new and separate instance of jQuery in each iframe.  The point of iframes is to be a unique and separate environment.  Why not just include a new instance of jQuery there rather than intermix the jQuery state among iframes?

Answer (score 2):

The only way to make jQuery available with a unique and consistent state that belongs solely to the iframe is to include the `<script>` tag that points to the jQuery script in each frame or dynamically load the script from each frame.  This will reinitialize the jQuery state separately for the frame.  There is no other way to get a new instance of jQuery for the iframe.

The browser will have the script in its cache after the first one so it won't be reloaded over the web each time.